# How can i use web scraping with Python to download multiple images? So far I've only manage to make it work with one image

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm reading the book Automate The Boring Stuff With Python and this is the practice project on chapter 12 (web scraping). I tried everything but only managed to make the code work with 1 image, not all the images from the page. Any ideas? Here is my code so far:

```
# Goes to a img site (in this case a blog), searches for a category of photos (in this case the comics) and
# downloads all the resulting images

import requests, os, bs4

# Downloads the URL.
url = 'http://cersibonforever.blogspot.com/'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
# Create the folder in path.
os.makedirs('cersibon', exist_ok = True)
# Find the images.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
post = soup.select('img[src]')
post = post[0].get('src')
if post == []:
    print('Could not find image.')
# Download the images.
else:
    res = requests.get(post)
    res.raise_for_status()
    # Saves the images to cersibon folder.
    print('Downloading %s to folder...' % (post))
    imageFile = open(os.path.join('cersibon', 'tirinha.jpg'), 'wb')
    for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
        imageFile.write(chunk)
    imageFile.close()
print('Done.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done everything right, but instead of selecting just the first post with `post = post[0].get('src')` you should iterate over then all, downloading every image with each source:

```py
import requests, os, bs4

# Downloads the URL.
url = 'http://cersibonforever.blogspot.com/'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
# Create the folder in path.
os.makedirs('cersibon', exist_ok = True)
# Find the images.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
all_post = soup.select('img[src]')

for post in all_post:
    src = post.get('src')
    if not src:
        print('Could not find image.')
    
    # Download the images.
    else:
        res = requests.get(src)
        res.raise_for_status()
        # Saves the images to cersibon folder.
        print('Downloading %s to folder...' % (src))
        imageFile = open(os.path.join('cersibon', 'tirinha.jpg'), 'wb')
        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            imageFile.write(chunk)
        imageFile.close()
        
print('Done.')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Iterating over the posts crossed my mind but I had 0 clue on how to do it on web scrapping. That really helped. I don't have enough rep to +1 your answer but hope this helps other in the future aswell